# UIButton image stretched after adding constraint

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I am in the process of making my app compatible from 4" display to 3.5" display. For this i am going with storyboard's auto layout option.

In the following view, after adding constraint to keep distance between UIButton and UILabel, 
the UIButton image is looks bigger ( I think it is stretched). UIButton view's content mode is  set to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. (Both in story board & programatically).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding height and width constraints.  Go to the pin menu (in the bottom right corner of the interface builder).  Check the boxes for height and width.  Add constraints.  That should keep the button at its size.